# Django save multiple versions of a Image within a class

Tags: python, django, class

I have the following function where the avatar the user has uploaded get's converted in two versions (smaller and larger version). Instead of writing this function multiple times for multiple fields of multiple models I would like to reimplement this as a class that I can reuse

This is my function:

```
def avatar_tamper(self):
    if self.avatar:
        if not (self.avatar_tn and os.path.exists(self.avatar_tn.path)):
            image = Image.open(self.avatar)
            outputIoStream = BytesIO()
            outputIoStream_tn = BytesIO()
            baseheight = 500
            baseheight_tn = 175
            hpercent = baseheight / image.size[1]
            hpercent_tn = baseheight_tn / image.size[1]
            wsize = int(image.size[0] * hpercent)
            wsize_tn = int(image.size[0] * hpercent_tn)
            imageTemproaryResized = image.resize((wsize, baseheight))
            imageTemproaryResized_tn = image.resize((wsize_tn, baseheight_tn))
            imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
            imageTemproaryResized_tn.save(outputIoStream_tn, format='PNG')
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            self.avatar = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                               "%s.png" % self.avatar.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                               sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            self.avatar_tn = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream_tn, 'ImageField',
                                                  "%s.png" % self.avatar.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                  sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream_tn), None)

    elif self.avatar_tn:
        self.avatar_tn.delete()
```

This is how I call the function at models.py save call:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    avatar_tamper(self)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return self.user
```

Can smb help?

Kind regards

Comment: Have you considered an image library ?

Answer (score 0):

Extending the model class allows the re-use of a method across multiple models.

Any model that extends `AvatarBase` will inherit the method and `my_image` field.

**models.py**

```
class AvatarBase(models.Model):
    my_image = models.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

    def avatar_tamper(self):
        if self.avatar:
            if not (self.avatar_tn and os.path.exists(self.avatar_tn.path)):
                image = Image.open(self.avatar)
                outputIoStream = BytesIO()
                outputIoStream_tn = BytesIO()
                baseheight = 500
                baseheight_tn = 175
                hpercent = baseheight / image.size[1]
                hpercent_tn = baseheight_tn / image.size[1]
                wsize = int(image.size[0] * hpercent)
                wsize_tn = int(image.size[0] * hpercent_tn)
                imageTemproaryResized = image.resize((wsize, baseheight))
                imageTemproaryResized_tn = image.resize((wsize_tn, baseheight_tn))
                imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
                imageTemproaryResized_tn.save(outputIoStream_tn, format='PNG')
                outputIoStream.seek(0)
                self.avatar = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                               "%s.png" % self.avatar.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                               sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
                outputIoStream.seek(0)
                self.avatar_tn = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream_tn, 'ImageField',
                                                  "%s.png" % self.avatar.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                  sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream_tn), None)

        elif self.avatar_tn:
            self.avatar_tn.delete()


class TheModel(AvatarBaseModel)
    ...model fields...

    
class TheOtherModel(AvatarBaseModel)
    ...model fields...
```

I would also recommend looking at a thumbnail library.

https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails

https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail

Both excellent choices and can be added to a model's method.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the issue for me using the following way:

some_file.py

```
def img_tamper(self, field):
    if getattr(self, field):
        if not (getattr(self, field + '_tn') and os.path.exists(getattr(self, field + '_tn').path)):
            image = Image.open(getattr(self, field))
            outputIoStream = BytesIO()
            outputIoStream_tn = BytesIO()
            baseheight = 500
            baseheight_tn = 175
            hpercent = baseheight / image.size[1]
            hpercent_tn = baseheight_tn / image.size[1]
            wsize = int(image.size[0] * hpercent)
            wsize_tn = int(image.size[0] * hpercent_tn)
            imageTemproaryResized = image.resize((wsize, baseheight))
            imageTemproaryResized_tn = image.resize((wsize_tn, baseheight_tn))
            imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
            imageTemproaryResized_tn.save(outputIoStream_tn, format='PNG')
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            setattr(self, field, InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                      "%s.png" % getattr(self, field).name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                      sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None))
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            setattr(self, field + '_tn', InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream_tn, 'ImageField',
                                                              "%s.png" % getattr(self, field).name.split('.')[0],
                                                              'image/png',
                                                              sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream_tn), None))

    elif getattr(self, field + '_tn'):
        getattr(self, field + '_tn').delete()
```

models.py

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    img_tamper(self, 'avatar')
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using this methode requierd that you have two fields at your model class: avatar and avatar_tn.

Thanks and kind regards to all folks that help me out here :D